# How to create a .wav file from data points of a sound wave

Tags: python-3.x, csv, wav

I have a csv file that contains data points of a sound wave, when I plot it in python matplotlib i get the follwoing image.[Figure of sound data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGb9G.png)

I want to turn that data into a .wav sound file to hear it.

Comment: Use [`wave`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/wave.html) and [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html). (Ask a vague question, get a vague response.)

Answer (score 1):

One way i see you could to this, is to serialize your datapoints that hold the sound information, and put them at the end of a wav header. The specification is here: http://soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat/.

Your datapoints look like they span from [-1,1], and so if you use 16bit (see BitsPerSample in spec.), you should normalize the datapoints to the range of a signed 16bit integer, which is roughly [-32000,32000]. Depending on the speed you want it to play back at, adjust the SampleRate parameter in the header. Save it as a .wav file and bobs your uncle.

Answer (score 0):

What worked great for me was to use this function : "scipy.io.wavfile.write" that one can find some documentation about [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.wavfile.write.html). More precisely, this example is very handy :

```
from scipy.io.wavfile import write
samplerate = 44100; fs = 100
t = np.linspace(0., 1., samplerate)
amplitude = np.iinfo(np.int16).max
data = amplitude * np.sin(2. * np.pi * fs * t)
write("example.wav", samplerate, data.astype(np.int16))
```

The sample rate can be taken higher than 44100 without any trouble. All it takes is a time-ordered list of values (int16 in the example).